# Vue fetch variable from service file in components but should maintain its own state

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have two components **Component A** and **Component B** and a service file which has all the constants **constants.js**

The **constants.js** file has a variable VMWARE_CONFIG

```
  VMWARE_CONFIG: [
    {
      name: "Production",
      selected: false,
      year: "1yr",
    },
    {
      name: "Development",
      selected: false,
      year: "1yr",
    }
 ]
```

This variable is being imported into **Component A** and **Component B** and is used a filter for further data processing

```
data() {
    return {
      priceList: null,
      search: null,
      mappedInstancesheader: Constants.MappedServerInstancesHeaders,
      unMappedServersheader: Constants.UnMappedServerInstancesHeaders,
      computeDetailsData: null,
      aws_migration_config: "all",
      slider: { label: "color", val: 25, color: "orange darken-3" },
      vmware_config: Constants.VMWARE_CONFIG,
      items: [],
    }
  }
```

The same code is being used in different components

The issue I am facing is that if user changes a filter on component A, it reflects on component B as well, I want to maintain different state for the variable for each components.

I can do one thing, to define the variable in each component itself but in reality this array object has more than 15 objects and is used in more than 3 components and there are 6 other variables with similiar use-case

Comment: So why did you share this config across these two components? if they are isolated, you should put them inside of every component in data part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Spread operators such as:

```
data() {
return {
  priceList: null,
  search: null,
  mappedInstancesheader: Constants.MappedServerInstancesHeaders,
  unMappedServersheader: Constants.UnMappedServerInstancesHeaders,
  computeDetailsData: null,
  aws_migration_config: "all",
  slider: { label: "color", val: 25, color: "orange darken-3" },
  vmware_config: [...Constants.VMWARE_CONFIG]
  items: [],
  }
}
```

[For more information, click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

The problem is:

When you import or use an array, you refer to its location in memory.
Thus, when you use and change the array, you change the array that is stored in memory, so everywhere it is used, it will change, since it is the same array.


The solution is:

Duplicating the array in memory, i.e. creating another array

The easiest way to do this by ES6 is Spread operators.

But you can also use libraries like lodash
[cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep)